# About the use of seek on gzip files

Tags: python, python-2.7, gzip, seek

I have a big `gzip` file and I would like to read only parts of it using `seek`.
About the use of `seek` on `gzip` files, this [page](http://pymotw.com/2/gzip/) says:

> The seek() position is relative to the uncompressed data, so the
>   caller does not even need to know that the data file is compressed.

Does this imply that `seek` has to read and decompress the data from the beginning of the file to the target position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. [This is the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/gzip.py#L567):

```
elif self.mode == READ:
    if offset < self.offset:
        # for negative seek, rewind and do positive seek
        self.rewind()
    count = offset - self.offset
    for i in range(count // 1024):
        self.read(1024)
    self.read(count % 1024)
```

[Alternatives are discussed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429987/compression-formats-with-good-support-for-random-access-within-archives) The problem is inherent to the `gzip` format.