# Read numpy data from GZip file over the network

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, gzip

I am attempting to download the [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) dataset and decode it without writing it to disk (mostly for fun).

```
request_stream = urlopen('http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')
zip_file = GzipFile(fileobj=request_stream, mode='rb')
with zip_file as fd:
    magic, numberOfItems = struct.unpack('>ii', fd.read(8))
    rows, cols = struct.unpack('>II', fd.read(8))
    images = np.fromfile(fd, dtype='uint8') # < here be dragons
    images = images.reshape((numberOfItems, rows, cols))
    return images
```

This code fails with `OSError: obtaining file position failed`, an error that seems to be ungoogleable. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem [seems to be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38061619/2397253), that what `gzip` and similar modules provide, aren't real file objects (unsurprisingly), but `numpy` attempts to read through the actual `FILE*` pointer, so this cannot work.

If it's ok to read the entire file into memory (which it might not be), then this can be worked around by reading all non-header information into a `bytearray` and deserializing from that:

```
rows, cols = struct.unpack('>II', fd.read(8))
b = bytearray(fd.read())
images = np.frombuffer(b, dtype='uint8')
images = images.reshape((numberOfItems, rows, cols))
return images
```