# Random-access compression in common use?

Tags: compression

Is there a standard library or unix tool used for random-access compression, read-only or read-write? By random-access, I mean that you can read or write any part of the compressed content.

There are a LOT of streaming tools (gzip, xz, etc) and a few archive member-based tools (zip) but I'm only aware of academic work on random-access generally. The main problem with archives is that they typically compress each file individually (no de-duplication across files).

Somewhat related to [Compression formats with good support for random access within archives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429987/compression-formats-with-good-support-for-random-access-within-archives) but re-asking because it's 10 years later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "read" part of your question, you can build an index to a large compressed file that creates a set of entry points into the compressed data. The number and density of those entry points determine how much data you need to decompress before you get to what you're looking for, and hence how fast the random access is. Note that *all* compressed data can be accessed randomly, since you always have one entry point at the start. You just decompress until you get what you want. Random read access is then not a question of ability, but a question of speed.

[zran.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zran.c) provides an example of building such an index for a gzip or zlib stream. You could do this for any compressed data format. Also [pigz](https://zlib.net/pigz/) will create a gzip stream with marked entry points using the `--independent` option. The [bzip2 format](https://github.com/dsnet/compress/blob/master/doc/bzip2-format.pdf) already has marked entry points for each block, where the entries are a few hundred K bytes of uncompressed data apart.

As for "or write", that's a whole different question. I am not aware of a format that facilitates random writing to compressed data. Generally, to get any level of decent compression, compressed data depends on all the data that precedes it. So if you write in the middle, you would need to decompress and recompress all of the data that follows.

To have true random write access, the format would have to solve two problems. The first would be to chunk the compressed data, like bzip2 or pigz's independent options do, to break the dependency on previous data. If you don't do that too often, there will only be a small impact to the compression ratio. Then you could take a chunk, decompress it, do your random write, and then recompress it. The smaller the chunks, the faster this random write access would be, but you have to trade that off with the compression ratio impact of smaller chunks.

The second problem to solve is the same one that file systems have, which is permitting fragmentation and non-sequential order. You want to avoid having to rewrite all of the subsequent chunks in the compressed data, due to the new randomly written chunk being smaller or larger. If you did rewrite, you're back to the random write taking a time proportional to the size of the compressed stream. The solution would be writing your own little file system built into the compressed data format that permits the chunks to not be in order in the stream, and for there to be unused gaps in the stream. I know of no format that does this, but it is possible in principle to implement.

If you limit your write access to appending, as would be the case for example for compressed logs, there are solutions for existing formats. [gzlog](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.h) is an example for appending to a gzip stream, allowing small amounts of data to be efficiently appended, leaving a valid gzip stream after each append.

Comment: Thanks for the links, although there's trade-offs to "entry point" methods if I'm trying to do it to save space via inter-file compression.

Comment: Re **possible** formats, this isn't really the question (since I am asking about what's available) but I think it's interesting. IMO you're thinking in a very stream-based way. This is, yes, the current state of things as far as I can tell, but I don't see any reason file compression need be done this way. There are possible formats that are wildly divergent from this approach. Imagine an index of deduplicated chunks, or there are academic grammar-based methods. Think more disk seeks :). lrzip (based on rsync) keeps a infinite-size LZ77-style "output" you can reference, as a real example.

Comment: No, the entry-points that zran.c makes have the history needed for each entry point. There is no impact on compression. No trade-off, other than the memory to hold the entry point information.

Comment: (Sorry, the text limit on comments is so small that I had to split things, and wasn't as clear as I could have been.) The trade off I reference is storing the larger size if you compress archive members individually (as in .zip), vs adding disk storage for 32K per entry point.

Possibly I am misunderstanding how zran.c works? Or maybe you are imagining re-generating the index each time, for some application, rather than persisting it?

Comment: Yes, I am taking random access to mean one application randomly accessing a compressed file many times, keeping the index in memory.

Comment: As noted, the pigz approach does not require history at the entry points, but then there is a very small impact to compression from discarding the history at those points when compressing. The zran.c approach has the advantage that it works on any gzip or zlib stream, with no requirements on how it was compressed.