# How to zgrep the last line of a gz file without tail

Tags: bash, shell, logging, grep

Here is my problem, I have a set of big `gz` log files, the very first info in the line is a datetime text, e.g.: 2014-03-20 05:32:00.

I need to check what set of log files holds a specific data.
For the init I simply do a:

```
           '-query-data-'
zgrep -m 1 '^20140320-04' 20140320-0{3,4}*gz
```

BUT HOW to do the same with the last line without process the whole file as would be done with zcat (too heavy):

```
zcat foo.gz | tail -1
```

Additional info, those logs are created with the data time of it's initial record, so if I want to query logs at 14:00:00 I have to search, also, in files created BEFORE 14:00:00, as a file would be created at 13:50:00 and closed at 14:10:00.

Comment: Because of the way compression works, it's not possible to read the end of a file without decompressing everything before it.

Comment: is there a pattern on grep to mach end of file, as it does for end of line `$`

Comment: No, there isn't. `zgrep` is essentially just piping `zcat` to `grep`, so whats wrong with `zcat foo.gz | tail -1 | grep`?

Comment: With big binaries they're lazy.

Comment: But since it's doing the same work as `zgrep`, you don't save anything by not using `zcat`.

Comment: @Barmar even with the `-m` option? Maybe to check this out only with the "use the Source", taking a look at zgrep's code. Does it work with bunches?/line by line?/whole file? If so, zgrep is barely an "alias" to `zcat | grep`...

Comment: It might actually be using `zlib` internally, but that has to do essentially the same work. `-m` stops reading from the input when it reaches the limit, but it still has to read from the beginning of the file until it gets there. I don't see how that's any help when you're trying to find the last line.

Comment: That helps to the first occurrence of a datetime in a file, so I know it fits, but for files created before my queried-datetime and fished after, it's faster to search backward.

Comment: The problem is that compressed data is hard to process backwards. Stream compression algorithms like LZW are based on adaptive algorithms, and the reader has to process the compressed data in order to learn the compressions as it goes.

Comment: Can you increase the frequency on `logrotate` (or whatever compresses the log files) so that you have smaller compressed files to search? That'll reduce the overhead of decompressing the file, which is a given.

Comment: @logrotate Only in the next version... and that would take a long long...

Comment: Is it an option to compress the file with bgzip and index the bgzipped file with tabix?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen maybe, but only for further versions. If you want to set it as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it is a sufficiently good answer. In the meantime I would like to direct you to these pages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429987/compression-formats-with-good-support-for-random-access-within-archives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236414/what-is-the-best-compression-algorithm-that-allows-random-reads-writes-in-a-file http://lh3.github.io/2014/07/05/random-access-to-zlib-compressed-files/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to alter your log rotation to create smaller files.

The second easiest solution would be to use a compression tool that supports random access.

Projects like [dictzip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dict/), [BGZF](http://blastedbio.blogspot.com/2011/11/bgzf-blocked-bigger-better-gzip.html), and [csio](https://github.com/hoxnox/csio) each add [sync flush points](http://www.bolet.org/~pornin/deflate-flush.html) at various intervals within gzip-compressed data that allow you to seek to in a program aware of that extra information.  While it exists in the standard, the vanilla `gzip` does not add such markers either by default or by option.

Files compressed by these random-access-friendly utilities are slightly larger (by perhaps 2-20%) due to the markers themselves, but fully support decompression with `gzip` or another utility that is unaware of these markers.

You can learn more at this question about [random access in various compression formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429987/compression-formats-with-good-support-for-random-access-within-archives).

There's also a "Blasted Bioinformatics" blog by Peter Cock with several posts on this topic, including:

- [BGZF - Blocked, Bigger & Better GZIP!](http://blastedbio.blogspot.com/2011/11/bgzf-blocked-bigger-better-gzip.html) – gzip with random access (like dictzip)
- [Random access to BZIP2?](http://blastedbio.blogspot.com/2011/11/random-access-to-bzip2.html) – An investigation (result: can't be done, though I do it below)
- [Random access to blocked XZ format (BXZF)](http://blastedbio.blogspot.com/2013/04/random-access-to-blocked-xz-format-bxzf.html) – xz with improved random access support

---

## Experiments with `xz`

[`xz`](http://tukaani.org/xz/) (an [LZMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Markov_chain_algorithm) compression format) actually has random access support on a per-block level, but you will only get a single block with the defaults.

### File creation

`xz` can concatenate multiple archives together, in which case each archive would have its own block.  The [GNU `split`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html) can do this easily:

```bash
split -b 50M --filter 'xz -c' big.log > big.log.sp.xz
```

This tells `split` to break `big.log` into 50MB chunks (*before* compression) and run each one through `xz -c`, which outputs the compressed chunk to standard output.  We then collect that standard output into a single file named `big.log.sp.xz`.

To do this without GNU, you'd need a loop:

```bash
split -b 50M big.log big.log-part
for p in big.log-part*; do xz -c $p; done > big.log.sp.xz
rm big.log-part*
```

### Parsing

You can get the list of block offsets with `xz --verbose --list FILE.xz`.  If you want the last block, you need its compressed size (column 5) plus 36 bytes for overhead (found by comparing the size to `hd big.log.sp0.xz |grep 7zXZ`).  Fetch that block using `tail -c` and pipe that through `xz`.  Since the above question wants the last line of the file, I then pipe that through `tail -n1`:

```bash
SIZE=$(xz --verbose --list big.log.sp.xz |awk 'END { print $5 + 36 }')
tail -c $SIZE big.log.sp.xz |unxz -c |tail -n1
```

### Side note

Version 5.1.1 introduced support for the `--block-size` flag:

```bash
xz --block-size=50M big.log
```

However, I have not been able to extract a specific block since it doesn't include full headers between blocks.  I suspect this is nontrivial to do from the command line.

## Experiments with `gzip`

`gzip` also supports concatenation.  I (briefly) tried mimicking this process for `gzip` without any luck.  `gzip --verbose --list` doesn't give enough information and it appears the headers are too variable to find.

This would require adding sync flush points, and since their size varies on the size of the last buffer in the previous compression, that's too hard to do on the command line (use dictzip or another of the previously discussed tools).

I did `apt-get install dictzip` and played with dictzip, but just a little.  It doesn't work without arguments, creating a (massive!) `.dz` archive that neither `dictunzip` nor `gunzip` could understand.

## Experiments with `bzip2`

`bzip2` has headers we can find.  This is still a bit messy, but it works.

### Creation

This is just like the `xz` procedure above:

```bash
split -b 50M --filter 'bzip2 -c' big.log > big.log.sp.bz2
```

I should note that this is *considerably* slower than `xz` (48 min for bzip2 vs 17 min for xz vs 1 min for `xz -0`) as well as considerably larger (97M for bzip2 vs 25M for `xz -0` vs 15M for xz), at least for my test log file.

### Parsing

This is a little harder because we don't have the nice index.  We have to guess at where to go, and we have to err on the side of scanning too much, but with a massive file, we'd still save I/O.

My guess for this test was 50000000 (out of the original 52428800, a pessimistic guess that isn't pessimistic enough for e.g. an H.264 movie.)

```bash
GUESS=50000000
LAST=$(tail -c$GUESS big.log.sp.bz2 \
         |grep -abo 'BZh91AY&SY' |awk -F: 'END { print '$GUESS'-$1 }')
tail -c $LAST big.log.sp.bz2 |bunzip2 -c |tail -n1
```

This takes just the last 50 million bytes, finds the binary offset of the last BZIP2 header, subtracts that from the guess size, and pulls that many bytes off of the end of the file.  Just that part is decompressed and thrown into `tail`.

Because this has to query the compressed file twice and has an extra scan (the `grep` call seeking the header, which examines the whole guessed space), this is a suboptimal solution.  See also the below section on how slow `bzip2` really is.

## Perspective

Given how fast `xz` is, it's easily the best bet; using its fastest option (`xz -0`) is quite fast to compress or decompress and creates a smaller file than `gzip` or `bzip2` on the log file I was testing with.  Other tests (as well as various sources online) suggest that `xz -0` is preferable to `bzip2` in all scenarios.

```
            ————— No Random Access ——————     ——————— Random Access ———————
FORMAT       SIZE    RATIO   WRITE   READ      SIZE    RATIO   WRITE   SEEK
—————————   —————————————————————————————     —————————————————————————————
(original)  7211M   1.0000       -   0:06     7211M   1.0000       -   0:00
bzip2         96M   0.0133   48:31   3:15       97M   0.0134   47:39   0:00
gzip          79M   0.0109    0:59   0:22                                  
dictzip                                        605M   0.0839    1:36  (fail)
xz -0         25M   0.0034    1:14   0:12       25M   0.0035    1:08   0:00
xz            14M   0.0019   16:32   0:11       14M   0.0020   16:44   0:00
```

Timing tests were not comprehensive, I did not average anything and disk caching was in use.  Still, they look correct; there is a very small amount of overhead from `split` plus launching 145 compression instances rather than just one (this may even be a net *gain* if it allows an otherwise non-multithreaded utility to consume multiple threads).

Comment: Thanks for the research. I would add that dictzip didn't work in your case because of the awkward "silent" limitation of 1.8 GB (see e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/1/dictzip). If only one file is to be compressed, simple concatenation of dictzip files (as allowed by the gzip standard) won't work. The only way to deal with the situation seems to be running `dictzip -t file.dz` (simple header checking): it either immediately fails or immediately succeeds.

Answer (score 3):

Well, **you can** access randomly a gzipped file if you previously create an *index* for each file ...

I've developed a command line tool which **creates indexes for gzip files which allow for very quick random access inside them**:
https://github.com/circulosmeos/gztool

The tool has two options that may be of interest for you:

- **-S** option supervise a still-growing file and creates an index for it as it is growing - this can be useful for gzipped rsyslog files as reduces to zero in the practice the time of index creation.
- **-t** tails a gzip file: this way you can do: `$ gztool -t foo.gz | tail -1`
  Please, note that if the index doesn't exists, this will consume the same time as a complete decompression: but as the index is reusable, next searches will be greatly reduced in time!

This tool is based on [zran.c demonstration code from original zlib](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zran.c), so there's no out-of-the-rules magic!