# Piping unzipped files to mongoimport

Tags: pipe, unzip, mongoimport

I have a zip archive with a lot of JSON files. Each of these JSON files is an array of JSON objects that I would like to import to a MongoDB collection. My idea was to use the pipe option of unzip and send the content of these files directly to mongoimport:

```
unzip -p archive.zip *.json | mongoimport -d db_name -c collection_name --jsonArray
```

I expected a similar behavior to what piping a find result does: each file is processed correctly, like with this command:

```
find . -type f -name "*.json" | zip archive.zip -@
```

But it isn't. Since the contents of the files is output to std, the mongoimport has a problem, because it gets a beginning of an array from another file right after an end of an array from the previous file. Nothing in between (apart from the newline I guess), so it stops.

Is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't found a one-liner that answers my problem (although I still believe that there is some potential in `sed` or `awk`), I chose to go with the `while` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARCHIVE_FILE="archive.zip"
unzip -l $ARCHIVE_FILE | awk 'NR>3{print $4}' | while IFS= read file ; do
  unzip -p $ARCHIVE_FILE "$file" | mongoimport -d db_name -c collection_name --jsonArray;
done
```

I assume here that `unzip -l` has universal format, which may not be the case, as suggested in comments for answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863093/read-the-files-one-by-one-in-a-zip-file-using-bash). So, in the future, I may need to go with some `grep` or `sed` on top of that.